# Is a perspective of a quasiconvex function still a quasiconvex function?

Tags: convex-analysis, convex-optimization

Given a function $f:\mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$, the perspective of $f$ is the functino $g:\mathbb{R}^{n+1}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ defined as
$$ (x,t) = tf(\frac{x}{t})$$
with domain $$ \textbf{dom} g = \{(x,t)| \frac{x}{t}\in\textbf{dom}f, t>0\}.$$

In the Chapter 3.2.6 of *Convex Optimization* by Boyd & Vendenberg, $g$ is convex if $f$ is convex. I wonder if the similar property hold for quasiconvex function. More precisely, **if $f$ is a quasiconvex function, is its perspective function $g$ also a quasiconvex function?**

I've tried to follow the approach to prove convexity of perspective function in the book, i.e., epigraph approach and definition approach (expercise 3.33). However, I'm not aware of any epigraph-kind concept for quasiconvex function, hence this approach doesn't work. I also tried using the sublevel set of quasiconvex function being a convex set and the image of perspective function over a convex set being convex. But I got myself lose along the process....

For using definition, I got stuck at some point. Here are my attenpt:

#### $\textbf{dom}g$ is a convex set

Given $(x_1,t_1), (x_2,t_2)\in\textbf{dom}g$, we want to show $(y,s)\in\textbf{dom}g$ with $y=\theta x_1 + (1-\theta)x_2$, $s = \theta t_1 + (1-\theta) t_2$, and $\theta \in [0,1]$. Hence, we need to show $\frac{y}{s} \in \textbf{dom}f $ and $s>0$. The second is apperent as $t_1>0$ and $t_2>0$. The first is show by:
$$\frac{y}{s} = \frac{\theta x_1 + (1-\theta) x_2}{\theta t_1 +(1-\theta) t_2}=\mu\frac{x_1}{t_1} + (1-\mu)\frac{x_2}{t_2}, $$
where $\mu = \frac{\theta x_1}{\theta t_1 + (1-\theta)t_2} \in [0,1] \quad \forall \theta\in[0,1]$. Since $\frac{x_1}{t_1}, \frac{x_2}{t_2} \in \textbf{dom}f$ and $\textbf{dom}f$ is a convex set, the convex combination $\frac{y}{s} \in \textbf{dom}f$.

#### $g(x,t)$ is quasiconvex (incomplete)

Here, I try to show $g(x,t)$ is quasiconvex given $f(x)$ is quasiconvex:
$$g(y,s) = sf(\frac{y}{s}) = sf(\mu\frac{x_1}{t_1} + (1-\mu)\frac{x_2}{t_2}) \leq s\cdot \max\{f(\frac{x_1}{t_1}), f(\frac{x_2}{t_2})\}$$
I couldn't establish that $s\cdot \max\{f(\frac{x_1}{t_1}), f(\frac{x_2}{t_2})\} \leq \max\{t_1 f(\frac{x_1}{t_1}), t_2f(\frac{x_2}{t_2})\}$ and got stuck.

Can anyone provide a counter example or complete the prove?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not true. Let $f(x) = \sqrt{|x|}$. Its perspective is
$$
g(x,t) = \sqrt{|x|}\sqrt t,
$$
which is not quasiconvex as
$$1=g(1,1) > \max (g(2,0),g(0,2)) = 0.$$

Comment: Thanks, @daw. Is there an intuitive way to understand why the statement is not true? I've been thinking hard to grasp it.